# How to fix multiple vote like?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

how to fix multiple like vote up in laravel 5 ?
user's 1 can like the post, after login again user's 1 can vote/like again. i want user's 1 only can vote/like once. how to fix it ?
this is my code :

in this user models

```
public function hasVotesPost(Posts $posts){
        return (bool) $posts->votes
            ->where('user_id', $posts->id)
            ->where('vote', get_class($posts))
            ->count() ;
}
```

in this controller

```
public function getVotes($post_id){
        $post_id = posts::find($post_id);
        if(!$post_id){
            return redirect()->route('/');
        }
        if(Auth::user()->hasVotesPost($post_id)){
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        $votes = $post_id->votes()->create([]);
        Auth::user()->votes()->save($votes);
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding properly? Not logged user can vote, and logged user can vote on the same post, and the problem is to recognize is it the same user? Specify where is the problem.

Comment: the problem , if am i login to user1 i can vote multiple click vote, in my problem i want i can vote up only one in the post. how to solution ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I assume that votes are storing only in one column and are only incrementing, so first thing that is required is a pivot table with foreign keys form post and user table. So point one, `create posts_users (post_id, user_id)` table.
Second thing is define relationship between posts and users.

Post model

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'posts_users ', 'post_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

change the way of storing data of votes for post on this

```
$post->users()->attach($user_id);
```

to check if user have voted on particular post is function

```
    function didUserVoteOnPost($user_id, $post_id)
    {
         $post = Post::where('id', '=', $post_id)->with(['user' => function($query) use($user_id){
              $query->where('user_id', '=' , $user_id);
         }]);
         if(!empty($post->pivot)) return true;
         return false;
     }
```

I did not test it, so You need to figure out bugs on Your own.

Comment: I do not understand , here I have 3 tables , the first table table users = id , name , email . The second table table posts = id , author_id , title , body . author_id associated with id on the users. and a third table tables votes = id , user_id , vote . user_id taken from the user id , and a vote taken of id on posts.

Comment: public function getVotes($post_id){
  $post_id = posts::find($post_id);
  if(!$post_id){
   return redirect()->route('/');
  }
  if(Auth::user()->hasVotesPost($post_id)){
   return redirect()->back();
  }
  $votes = $post_id->votes()->create([]);
  Auth::user()->votes()->save($votes);

  return redirect()->back();
 } ---> this is my postController

Comment: public function votes(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Vote','user_id');
 }

 public function hasVotesPost(Posts $posts){
  return (bool) $posts->votes
   ->where('user_id', $posts->id)
   ->where('vote', get_class($posts))
   ->count() ;
 } ----> this is my user model

Comment: public function votes(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Vote','vote');
 }  ------> and this my post model